# Writing a times table?

Tags: javascript

I know this may seem like a simple question but I'm stumped. I'm supposed to create a times table using increments of 12. While I can use any method, I'm attempting to use a for loop. The formula works just fine, it multiplies 'number' by 12, but I need to put, for instance, 12 * 1 = 12, rather than 12 * = 12 which is what I have now. Is there anything that I can do to improve upon this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
  var number = 0;
    i = 0

    for (number; number <=12; number++) {
      document.write("12 * " +  number * 12 + "</br>");
      i++;
    }



  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `12 * = 12, rather than 12 * = 12`

Comment: `document.write("12 * " +  number + " = " + (12*number) + "</br>")` is probably closer to what you want, though it's hard to tell from the current question wording. (Parentheses around `(12*number)` just for readability, given `*` has higher precedence than `+`.) Also, you don't need the `i` variable given its value is never used, and you should set `number = 0` in the first part of the `for`.

Comment: my apologies. I edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may be what you're trying to accomplish, which involves ensuring you output the value of your iterating variable (`number` in this case).

```js
var number = 0;

for (number; number <=12; number++) {
  document.write("12 * " + number + " = " + number * 12 + "</br>");
}
```